# spring batch KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access

Tags: spring, multithreading, apache-kafka, spring-batch

I am new to sporing batch. I have requirement which need to read kafka stream and filter data & save in database. For That I have used spring batch with KafkaItemReader. When I run start multiple jobs in spring job it gives **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access** Error. In this Time It only run last job only.

This is the spring batch config.

```
    @Autowired
    TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Bean
    KafkaItemReader<Long, Event> kafkaItemReader() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);
        props.putAll(this.properties.buildConsumerProperties());
        return new KafkaItemReaderBuilder<Long, Event>()
                .partitions(0)
                .consumerProperties(props)
                .name("event-reader")
                .saveState(true)
                .topic(topicName)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor=new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
        asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(5);
        return asyncTaskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean(name = "JobLauncher")
    public JobLauncher simpleJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }
```

And there Is controller End Point which start new jobs. This is the way I have to use start new Job

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("JobLauncher")
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;


    Map<String, JobParameter> items = new HashMap<>();
    items.put("userId", new JobParameter("UserInputId"));
    JobParameters paramaters = new JobParameters(items);
    try {
        jobLauncher.run(job, paramaters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have seen that KafkaItemReader is not thread [safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53847066/getting-kafkaconsumer-is-not-safe-for-multi-threaded-access-error-when-i-use-cur). I want to know is this way correct or Is there any way to read kafka streams in multi threaded spring batch environment.
Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `KafkaItemReader` is documented to be non thread safe, here is an excerpt from its [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/kafka/KafkaItemReader.html):

```
Since KafkaConsumer is not thread-safe, this reader is not thread-safe.
```

So using it in a multi-threaded environemnt is incorrect and not conform to the documentation. What you can do is use a reader per partition.

Comment: Thanks for your Quick reply. Your are the one who write this library know. I am new to spring batch & kafka as well. Is there any documentation which I can prefer for kafka reader partition

Answer (score 1):

As per spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/kafka/KafkaItemReader.html), it uses KafkaConsumer; which itself is not threadsafe as per their detailed [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) .

Please see if you can use any of approach (i.e. decoupling or single consumer per thread) as mentioned on that documentation.  In your example, you may need to use separate handler for taskexecutor (if you follow decoupling approach).

Comment: Thanks for Quick Reply. Is there any documentation I can prefer for decouple task manager.

Comment: In your joblauncher, don't set taskexecutor as you are doing currently. That will make tight coupling. Instead, call some handler which will in turn call task-executor.  Handler is separate class & that class can call your task executor.