# Limit number of messages from Kafka in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, concurrentlinkedqueue

I am storing the data from KafkaListener in a ConcurrentLinkedQueue to be processed. Currently it consumes as many data as it can and completely fills up RAM. How do I limit the number of messages in the queue so that when it reaches the limit the KafkaListener pauses.

```java
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

@KafkaListener(
        topics = "topic",
        id = "topic-kafka-listener",
        groupId = "batch-processor",
        containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory"
)
public void receive(@NotNull @Payload List<Message> messages) {
    queue.addAll(messages);
}
```

How do I limit the queue size to say 1 million?
Whenever the queue is polled and there is free space it should start listening again.

OR

How do I limit the rate at which Kafka consumes messages to say 100,000 messages per second?

Comment: Why store it in a queue? Why not just process it directly? What is the added benefit here? Feels like what you are doing with the queue is already doable with Kafka in the first place.

Comment: I need to batch process the data using spring batch. and the item reader of spring batch polls data one by one. I figured concurrent linked list is the best option to use. So Kafka will keep getting data while spring batch keeps processing it.

Comment: Use a chunk, yes it will be pulled one by one but processed in a chunk. But if this is unlimited stream why use Spring Batch in the first place. Also you probably want to specify the number of messages to pull instead of shoehorning your own layer on top of that (which will lead to this problem).

Comment: I used `KafkaConsumer` instead to create a consumer object and called it before the job starts. with this i can set the number polled and the length of time to  poll.

Comment: Spring Batch has a Kafka item reader. https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/kafka/KafkaItemReader.html

Comment: I first tried with KafkaItemReader but it gave ConcurrentModificationException. I found that it is not thread safe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247780/spring-batch-kafkaconsumer-is-not-safe-for-multi-threaded-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using annotation I used the `KafkaConsumer` object to poll for data manually. With this there is more control.

```java
Map<String, Object> consumerConfig = Map.of(
        "bootstrap. Servers", "localhost:9092",
        "key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class,
        "value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class,
        "group.id", "batch-processor",
        "max.poll.records", 480000
);
KafkaConsumer<String, Message> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerConfig);

kafkaConsumer.subscribe(List.of("topic"));
```

```java
public void receive()    {
    ConsumerRecords<String, Message> consumerRecords = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
    consumerRecords.forEach(record -> queue. Add(record. Value()));
}
```

Comment: Which you could have achieved as well with the listener. Using the `properties` attribute ad specify the `max.poll.records` in there. But still why the queue, it feels like added complexity with something that you should be doing using kafka, it feels like you are working around it instead of embracing it.

Comment: I wasn't able to set the time it polls for with the listener. With this each time I run the job I can set how much data the job works with.
Coming to the queue I couldn't think of any other way to give data to the item reader in spring batch. If there is a way to skip the queue I welcome it since it will reduce my RAM usage and latency.

Comment: As I stated, set the chunk size. That is the number of elements it will read and process. No need to add an additional queue.

Comment: can you please give me a code example with @KafkaListener and spring batch with its item reader? It will give me a clearer view and I will be able to understand it better.

Comment: And with listener if i set `max.poll.records` it will still consume that max number multiple times because it runs like in a loop. how can i make it consume only once?

Comment: You nowhere mentioned you want to consume once? Why? I don't get your usecase, the listener will always continue to consume and stuff things in your own queue as well. Feels to me like you are trying to receive and process x messages in one batch. At least that is what you initially started out with.

Comment: I want to limit the consumption to a certain number of messages so that my system doesn't get overloaded. Even if 5 million messages are sent to kafka there will at most be 1 million messages that are consumed by my system and ready for processing.
If it consumes all 5M then my ram will get full.

Comment: Why would your ram get full? I don't get that. 1 message will be processed and discarded, no memory is being kept. If you execute in batches (process 1000, confirm next 1000, there is no memory issue as well). The problem is that you are using a queue and storing everything in memory. You have introduced the problem yourself.

Comment: I am to use Spring Batch to process and save the data to a db. Spring batch has steps that include an item reader that will fetch data from a source and pass it on to item processor or item writer. Currently in my code the queue acts as the source. I do not know how to make the kafkalistener the source directly. If you know the correct method please show me a code snippet. Thanks

Comment: As stated before there is a `KafkaItemReader` for that. Ditch the whole queue stuff. You are trying to optimize things that don't need to be optimized.

Comment: `KafkaItemReader` is not thread safe as stated [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/kafka/KafkaItemReader.html#:~:text=Since%20KafkaConsumer%20is%20not%20thread%2Dsafe%2C%20this%20reader%20is%20not%20thread%2Dsafe.). Because of this I can not run the step with thread pool. I've tried it before and it gives `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: You can wrap it in a `SyncronizedItemReader` to make it more thread safe. For the processor and writer it doesn't make a difference. You could also run multple jobs one per partition you have on the topic. That way you don't need a multi threaded reader.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Consumer can be paused and resumed by API. Check this methods for details:

- [KafkaConsumer.pause()](https://kafka.apache.org/35/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#pause(java.util.Collection))
- [KafkaConsumer.resume()](https://kafka.apache.org/35/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#resume(java.util.Collection))